# get values of object in an array with another array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects :

```
let formInputs = [
    {"name" : "NOM_MANDATAIRE", "fieldType": "input", "type": "text", "values": []},
    {"name" : "SECTEUR_VENTE", "fieldType": "select", "type": null, "values": [
        {"key": "1", "value": "text of the select"},
        {"key": "2", "value": "text of the select"}
    ]},
    {"name" : "TITRE_VERSION", "fieldType": "input", "type": "text", "values": []},
];
```

I use a forEach to get each objects and manipulate them :

```
formInputs.forEach(element => {
    console.log(element.name);
    ...
    for (let items in element.values) {
        for (item in items) {
            console.log(item.key);
        }
    }
}
```

My issue is that i'm stuck when I want to retrieve the object associated to the key "values". 
In the forEach block i also tried to use a for each :

item returns 0 and item.key returns undefined.

Comment: The problem is you're using `for-in` to loop through an array. That's almost never what you want, `items` in your outer loop is a *string* containing the value `"0"`, then `"1"`, etc. In ES2015+ (which you seem to be using), `for-of` is what you're looking for, but see the linked question's answers for more options. Basically: ```for (const {values} of formInputs) {
    for (const entry of values) {
        /* ... */
    }
}``` https://pastebin.com/PYSGa2gG Or that inner one might be `for (const {key} of values) { /*...*/ }` if you just want the `key`.

Comment: Try this.. formInputs.forEach(element => {
  for (let item of element.values) {
    console.log("key=", item['key']);
    console.log("value=", item['value']);
  }
});

Comment: your let item of element.values work fine ! thanks ! I'm always confused with for in and of.